# Показать последние даты для каждого ID

Tags: sql

Всем привет. Есть такое задание -  For given Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) data show the latest record per each ID. Т.Е. вернуть последнюю запись с датой для каждого ID. Есть такое CTE

```
with tabl(id, b, ts) as (values
(1, 'Data1_1', '2020-02-03 00:00:00'), (1, 'Data1_1', '2020-03-04 00:05:00'), (1, 'Data1_1', '2020-01-02 01:00:00'),
(3, 'Data3_1', '2020-01-03 00:00:00'), (3, 'Data3_1', '2020-03-04 00:05:00'), (3, 'Data3_1', '2025-01-02 01:00:00'),
(2, 'Data1_1', '2020-03-03 00:00:00'), (2, 'Data1_1', '2021-03-04 00:05:00'), (2, 'Data2_1', '2025-01-02 01:00:00'))
```

Вопрос состоит в том - как сделать это задание в контексте предиката EXISTS? Должно получиться как то так

```
SELECT ts 
FROM tabl t1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT ts
        FROM tabl t2
        WHERE t2.ts = t1.ts
        AND .......
        )
```

и еще меня смущает то, что сами даты представлены в виде строкового типа, использовать агрегатную функцию MAX() запрещается

Comment: *как сделать это задание в контексте предиката EXISTS?* Сформулировать так - вывести запись, если НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ запись с датой больше текущей.

Comment: @Akina это AND NOT t2.ts < t1.ts? и у меня походу что то в коде не то...

Comment: Да, оно. Плюс равенство по `id` - в соответствии с заданием. Ну и НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ кагбэ должно быть NOT EXISTS.

Comment: SELECT ts 
FROM tabl t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT id
        FROM tabl t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
        AND t2.ts > t1.ts
        ) По красоте получилось... ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБОЧКИ